# ksh: parameter not set issue. quite weird

Tags: parameters, ksh

I met a quite weird issue when running **ksh** and drive me crazy ...

OS : Redhat

ksh: ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21

```
#!/bin/ksh -eu
echo "hello"
echo "main_class: $abc"
```

I got this error :

```
hello
./aaa: line 3: abc./aaa: line 3: : parameter not set
```

while, if change to below, looks like a normal "parameter not set" error:

```
    #!/bin/ksh -eu
    echo "hello"
    echo "main_class: $ac"
```

error message :

```
hello
./aaa: line 3: ac: parameter not set
```

Can you help explain this  ?

Comment: anyways of the feature of the errors, i see you are trying to echo a string and a variable, but i dont see a variable declaration...... btw i run your code as well on ksh (both ways), and it doesnt print out an error just prints everything but the variable which is null and not set. `hello
main_class: `

Comment: @hedgehog, did you add "#!/bin/ksh -eu" in the very first line of your script ? at least , you should see a "parameter not set "error.  The reason that those variables were not declared is by purpose, the whole story is a little complex, but the main point is just as i said in the thread.

Comment: yes i surely did add it, and it doesnt produce any error at all running in ksh, it just were the variable should be it leaves it empty.. btw i run it in ksh in a solaris system., weird actually, that it doesnt produce the error.....

Comment: My guess is that the original script had some non-printing character in line 3.  Were you able to reproduce the error after editing the `ac` back to `abc`?